# Find a variable in a array variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am trying to get load a variable from a array variable for my project but the value comes back as `undefined` I just used the `console.log` for the test output.
I want to learn how to use it after seeing others use on their projects and I want to do it to make my projects easier to manage.
I set it to trigger when the page loads up first thing.

Any help is welcome from the community.

**My code if it helps solve it problem:**

```js
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
var values = [
odds_base = 10,
start_cash = 50
]

console.log(values.odds_base)
});
```

Comment: Are you sure `values` is array

Comment: ```var values ={
odds_base :10,
start_cash : 50
}```

Comment: if that is array then you should use this `console.log(odds_base)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong data structure here. Square brackets are used for arrays. You should use a javascript object here.

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    var values = {
        odds_base: 10,
        start_cash: 50
    }
    
    console.log(values.odds_base)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case I think you have to use an object like this one, instead of array:

```
window.addEventListener('load',function() {
    var values = {
        odds_base: 10,
        start_cash: 50
    };
    
    console.log(values.odds_base);
});
```

Comment: it's not a `JSON` but just an object.

Comment: How do I get the data from the array @Murilo Góes de Almeida

Comment: @JoeMcMullan please be more specific (maybe ask a separate question?) what "get", "the data" and "the array" is

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do like this

```js
let values = {};

values.odds_base = 10;
values.start_cash = 50;

console.log(values.odds_base);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is array then you have to use variables like this

```js
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
var values = [
odds_base = 10,
start_cash = 50
]

console.log(values);
console.log(odds_base);
console.log(start_cash);
});
```

**When you assign array like this then Internally JavaScript first Creates the variable and then assign those variables in array**

Otherwise convert that array to object and do like as follows

```js
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
var values = {
odds_base : 10,
start_cash : 50
}

console.log(values);
console.log(values.odds_base);
console.log(values.start_cash);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `values` looks like it should be an `object` and not an array as seen in your example *i.e.*  `values = [ a = 1, b = 2 ]` should be `values = { a: 1, b: 2 }`

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   var values = {
        odds_base: 10,
        start_cash: 50
    }
    console.log(values.odds_base)
});
```

Tip: Declare the `values` variable outside the scope of the `addEventListener` callback if you wish it to be accessible outside also.

Comment: Can I use `values.odds_base` with the example

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then yes but only within the scope is has been declared in. You cannot use it outside of that `load` callback function unless you declare `values` outside.